# spl-token-2022 compilation error in anchor build

Tags: anchor, spl-token, anchor-lang

I am running `anchor build` and faced into an issue mentioned on Anchor discord.[image]

After fixing this issue by adding to dependencies, now I am facing this error even if I do not use `spl-token-2022`. Here is the Cargo.toml file.

```
[dependencies]
solana-program = "1.14.16"
anchor-spl = "0.27.0"
num-derive = "0.3.3"
num-traits = "0.2.15"
nom = "7"
spl-token = "3.5.0"
spl-associated-token-account = {version = "1.0.3", features = ["no-entrypoint"]}
switchboard-v2 = "0.1.23"

anchor-lang = { version = "0.27.0", features = ["init-if-needed"] }
winnow = "=0.4.1"
toml_datetime = "=0.6.1"
```

Error msg (ignoring long top log). Not code from my program.

```
...
error[E0609]: no field `destination_ciphertext` on type `&solana_zk_token_sdk::instruction::WithdrawWithheldTokensData`
    --> src/extension/confidential_transfer/processor.rs:1143:21
     |
1143 |         &proof_data.destination_ciphertext,
     |                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ unknown field
     |
     = note: available fields are: `context`, `proof`
help: one of the expressions' fields has a field of the same name
     |
1143 |         &proof_data.context.destination_ciphertext,
     |                     ++++++++

Some errors have detailed explanations: E0061, E0599, E0609.
For more information about an error, try `rustc --explain E0061`.
error: could not compile `spl-token-2022` due to 43 previous errors
```

In Cargo.lock, there are two spl-token-2022 package with version 0.5.0 and 0.6.1 each.

```
[[package]]
name = "anchor-spl"
version = "0.27.0"
source = "registry+https://github.com/rust-lang/crates.io-index"
checksum = "75cc8066fbd45e0e03edf48342c79265aa34ca76cefeace48ef6c402b6946665"
dependencies = [
 "anchor-lang",
 "solana-program",
 "spl-associated-token-account",
 "spl-token",
 "spl-token-2022 0.5.0",
]

[[package]]
name = "spl-associated-token-account"
version = "1.1.3"
source = "registry+https://github.com/rust-lang/crates.io-index"
checksum = "978dba3bcbe88d0c2c58366c254d9ea41c5f73357e72fc0bdee4d6b5fc99c8f4"
dependencies = [
 "assert_matches",
 "borsh",
 "num-derive",
 "num-traits",
 "solana-program",
 "spl-token",
 "spl-token-2022 0.6.1",
 "thiserror",
]
```

Comment: Have exactly the same

Answer (score 5):

This fixed it for me:

```
anchor-lang = { git = "https://github.com/coral-xyz/anchor.git", features = ["init-if-needed"]}
anchor-spl = { git = "https://github.com/coral-xyz/anchor.git"}
```

It seems the issue stems from a certain version of spl-token-2022 with a deprecated dependency. The newer one works for me so far.

Comment: How can i fix this with the new 0.28.0. If i point to git, it takes from 0.28.0 but i want to stay in 0.27.0 since my other deps would break.